# Declare local functions with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, scope, global

I have the next singleton:

```
(
    function () 
    {
        require
        (
            ['module'], 
            function () 
            {
                module();
            }
        );
    }
)();
```

module.js:

```
function module () 
{
    alert('yay');
}
```

However, when I go to my console, I see that module is defined in the global scope, **something that I don't want**, because I want all my dependencies inside my singleton scope.

I understand that one of the purposes of require.js is to avoid global pollution, so, *how do I protect my dependencies from the global scope the way I want?*

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc , or http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `require.js` in the correct way.

You are supposed to use `define` function in order to define a module.
In file module.js:

```
define (function() {
    return function(){
        alert('yay');
    }
});
```

The module value is what you return from the outer function.
Then, to require the module, use this code:

```
require(['module'], function (module) {
    module();
});
```

In this way, the global is not polluted. You can also define a module that require other modules in this way:

```
define (["aModule","anotherModule"],function(aModule,anotherModule) {
    return function(){
        alert(anotherModule.someThing + aModule.aProperty);
    }
});
```

Also, you can define more than a module in the same file. You just have to name them:

```
define("module1",["aModule","anotherModule"],function(aModule,anotherModule) {
    return function(){
        //a module could be a function, an object or whatever you want
        return "this module value is a string";
    }
});

define("module2",["module1","anotherModule"],function(module1,anotherModule) {
    return function(){
        alert(module1 + anotherModule.aProperty);
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about that, I was trying to figure out how require.js works, it was very confusing, but your answer is the correct, I'll accept you in a couple minutes, thank you! :)